# KeyError: '/Root' in PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I tried appending one PDF

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

attachment = 'C:/Users/John Doe/Desktop/test.pdf'

merger = PdfMerger()

merger.append(attachment)
```

and it gives me this error.

```
"C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\Joe Medina\Desktop\Joseph\Geoscope\Binders\tests.py"
incorrect startxref pointer(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\Desktop\Joseph\Geoscope\Binders\tests.py", line 10, in <module>
    merger.append(attachment)
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_utils.py", line 390, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_merger.py", line 283, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, outline_item, pages, import_outline)
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_utils.py", line 390, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_merger.py", line 174, in merge
    pages = (0, len(reader.pages))
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py", line 2033, in __len__
    return self.length_function()
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 446, in _get_num_pages
    self._flatten()
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1074, in _flatten
    catalog = self.trailer[TK.ROOT].get_object()
  File "C:\Users\Joe Medina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 149, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).get_object()
KeyError: '/Root'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can merge all PDFs except for some special cases like this one.

Weirdly enough, when I "Save as" the PDF into the PDF of the same name, the program works. the PDF Versions are just the same when I save them.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a PyPDF2 bug. Have you tried submitting a bug report?

Comment: Not yet. I'll wait for a few more days before submitting a report.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2 (only pypdf is still maintained).

This sounds like a bug to me. Please submit a bug report: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues

A good bug report contains:

1. Your Code
2. All necessary files
3. All versions of packages (please move to pypdf first)

Comment: Did this bug ever get filed? I don't see it, and I'm hitting the `KeyError: '/Root'` exception with 3.7.0, so I can file it, but it's near impossible to search the issues page for the word "Root"

Comment: If you have it with 3.7.0 and you can share the file with us, please go ahead!

Comment: Done: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1756

Comment: Did this issue has been debugged? @Oded

Comment: The robustness improvement was released with `pypdf>3.7.1`.